# Create an Inner Join for rows not exist with 0 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

- First one `Week` table
- Second `Reference` table
- Third table `Inner` table

but I have some problem with inner table.

I want to add some rows that not exist in inner table same as `Final_table`
and put 0 for rows that not exist in inner table

I need query in SQL to do it.

Please note that I have inner table and I don't create it from `tblWeek` and `Reference` table, but I can use them

```
Week                            
01.08.2016                          
08.08.2016                          
16.08.2016
```

Final_table

```
                Week    RefNumber   Value   
RefNumber       01.08.16    100 15  
100             01.08.16    200 3   
200             01.08.16    300 0   
300             08.08.16    100 8   
                08.08.16    200 0   
                08.08.16    300 0   
                16.08.16    100 0   
                16.08.16    200 0   
                16.08.16    300 7
```

Full_tbl

```
Week    RefNumber   Value                   
01.08.16    100 15                  
01.08.16    200 3                   
08.08.16    100 8                   
16.08.16    200 7
```

[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase what you are actually trying to do? Maybe use some punctuation as well?

Comment: Can you provide the sample data as text?  Ideally as a temp table or table variable (see this question for [help and advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `Right Join` and `Cross Join`

```
SELECT X.WEEK,X.RefNumber,ISNULL(T.Value,0) AS Value
FROM [Full_Tbl] T
    RIGHT JOIN
        (SELECT  WEEK,RefNumber
            FROM [WEEK] 
         CROSS JOIN [RefNumber] ) X
         ON X.[WEEK]=T.[Week] AND X.[RefNumber] = T.[RefNumber]
ORDER BY X.[WEEK]
```

Comment: I Appreciate your Help

Answer (score 0):

I hope i got your question right (mainly from the image attached).

Here, this should work:

```
SELECT f.week, f.refnumber, (CASE WHEN f.value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE f.value END) as value
FROM Full_tbl f
RIGHT JOIN refnumber on  f.refnumber = refnumber.refnumber
```

Basically what we do is:

1. we get all the lines from the 'refnumber' table (thats the RIGHT JOIN).
2. we use case if the value associated with this refnumber is NULl to be presented as 0.

Answer (score 0):

We can `union all` a `cross join` that uses `where not exists()` to get all to combinations of `Week` and `RefNumber` that do not exist in `inner_table`.

```
select [Week], RefNumber, [Value]
  from inner_table
union all
select [Week], RefNumber, [Value]=0
  from [Week] w
    cross join RefNumber r
  where not exists (
      select 1 
      from inner_table as i
      where i.[Week] = w.[Week]
        and i.RefNumber = r.RefNumber
      )
```